# Laptop battery reset

Tags: reset, laptop

I've replaced the cells in a laptop battery. So far, it is working...sort of.  I replaced it with 18650 cells from a legitimate company (panasonic) to help ensure I wasn't getting garbage like those ultra fire batteries I read about.  Ended up being 8 3.7volt, 3400mah cells wired in pairs to give me 14.8v.  The issue I am facing is the battery seems to be matching the old battery's charge cycle/capacity.  In other words, the battery was getting old and only giving me about 30-45 minutes of battery life and would take about 45-60 minutes to charge, and that's about what the new setup is giving me.

My research thus far has indicated that they build these packs with some sort of controller that monitors the battery to keep if from over charging/discharging, etc.  I've also found that some people have had luck with resetting this memory by grounding one of the legs of the ic chips on the circuit board of the battery (eeeprom reset?).

If this is the case, is there information I can provide that would enable someone here to help me figure out how to do that?  I can take pictures, provide model numbers off the chips (one of them is nt1908)...whatever is needed.  Otherwise, I've unfortunately wasted $50 on a set of 18650 cells :(

Comment: Anytime rechargeable lithium batteries are used, a controller must also be used to prevent fires from over-charging, as the electrolytes used in rechargeable lithium batteries are highly volatile and will combust as soon as they're exposed to the atmosphere _(this is why the warning against puncturing rechargeable lithium batteries exists)_.  If there's no way to clear the memory of the controller, a few complete recharge/discharge cycles _should_ get it working correctly - disable all power management in the OS to prevent the battery from sleeping/hibernating/powering off at 5% capacity.

Answer (score 1):

What a load of pseudo-science was the answer. The Li-Ion chemistry has the same 3.7V rating since at least 15 years ago, with 4.2V cap voltage. I still have the dead battery of a 2003 Compaq laptop and the cells are 2200mAh (2P4S) with the same specs as today's cells when I found the Panasonic datasheets. The chemistry has advanced for all cells, they are more robust, have higher capacity, longer life, and for Li-polymer increased cap voltage to 4.3V and 4.4V, but those cells are pouch type and used in smartphones, tablets and the most advanced laptops (those metal body slim laptops) due to higher energy density. Regular laptops, with low specs, stick with the cylindrical type cells, the cheapest and also more robust. The cylindrical 18650 type cells will work fine with any BMS controller from years ago, because it was designed with the specs still valid today.

The only thing that will be different will be the time required to charge the new cells if the capacity is higher than the original, since the peak current is fixed from the factory. The charging algorithm is the same CC-CV, constant current until a certain voltage, then constant voltage at 4.15-4.2V, so higher capacity will require higher time to reach CV mode, but this is absolutely fine.

Your problem, by now probably gone, since this post is 2 years old, is the BMS controller that doesn't know the cells have been replaced, and uses the same data of the degraded cells. The procedure to reset/wipe controller data and start fresh, with new capacity data, is proprietary. The battery has an I2C bus that is accessed by the OS or BIOS. But there is hope, since the controller is continuously monitoring the battery pack for actual charge capacity, at least two full cycles charge-discharge should replace the old data. Of course, the controller will report the original capacity set at factory calibration, that is stored somewhere, probably in its non-volatile memory, if it has one, or in a separate non-volatile memory chip on the board. But if the measured capacity is the one of the new cells, then is fine and over few cycles will report correctly the charge state.

I just replaced the cells on a Vaio laptop (10.8V, 3500mAh, 2P3S) and initially it reported the 25% left capacity from the old cells, but after 2 cycles it went to ~5000mAh of the new cells. At the third cycle it reported correctly the charge state, at 2% left the laptop stopped, then reported a full charge 5200mAh. The cells are taken from two fresh HAMA external battery packs. What was interesting after first boot was the reporting of charge cycle count as zero, taking out the cells left the controller without power and erased the number of charge cycles, so it was volatile data. I don't know where the old measured capacity is stored, but now is ok at 10 cycles. Yeah, the controller still says the designed capacity is 3500mAh, but the measured one is 5200mAh. The laptop now works for about ~7 hours of browsing and movies, from the original ~4.5 hours. The cells cost was 25$, while a replacement battery from a third party supplier costs 60-70$. And the satisfaction of fixing this thing and reviving and old laptop that still works great, priceless.

Answer (score 0):

Laptops use so-called "smart batteries", meaning that the battery pack has built in charger that (a) charges each parallel cell group to their manufacturer's specifications (terminal voltage and max charging current), and (b) balances the charge between groups connected in series.

When you measured 14.8 (3.7V times 4) on a freshly charged battery (I presume), it means that the charger in your re-used pack was charging the new cells to 3.7V. Most recent 18650 cells usually have termination voltage at 4.2V, so if you charge then only to to 3.7V, their capacity will be severely handicapped. So, you need to check charging specifications for your new cells first. However, it will be highly unlikely that you can reprogram the built-in charger to new 4.2V level.

The second effect could be due to the battery configuration having two cells in parallel, 4S2P. Manufacturers of good laptop batteries use careful binning technique to [closely match the cells](http://4wings.com/lib/files/bat.pdf) that will go in parallel. If discharge curves and/or internal impedances are not matched, the pair of parallel cells will receive suboptimal charge, and will have stronger self-discharge, so the overall battery capacity will be further reduced.

Because of the above considerations, an attempt to repair/replace bad cells in laptop battery packs in DIY environment has usually a limited success.